# Can't hide div before alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a request for removing a div and showing an alert. Therefore, my first code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#headerDiv').hide();

 alert('something wants to say');

});
```

It didn't the hide div before the alert in chrome and edge, so I change the alert line to

```
setTimeout(function(){

 alert('something wants to say');

},100);
```

It works fine but I want to know why it happens. Furthermore, I think the problem can occur again depending on computer performance, so I want to know if there is any quality fix or not.

Comment: JS and browser rendering are run in the same thread. All the JS is executed before the browser can render any changes to a page. `alert` blocks the JS execution until user closes the box. The timed alert is a solution, or you can use a non-blocking alert box (a library or your own implementation).

Comment: Are you sure the `#headerDiv` element exists ?

Comment: The browser doesn't have time to repaint before the alert fires, by using a timeout you delay the alert until the next tick, when the repaint has completed.

Comment: I'm sure about the existance of element. Can I ask the reason that explorer works fine in original code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` is pushed at the end of the current stack execution, hence gives the browser the time to interrupt the JS and render the changes.
`setTimeout` is a possible solution to this.

One other possibility could be to fire an event after the `.hide()` that triggers the `alert`.

(you can find more about the `setTimeout` implementation [here](https://qdivision.io/javascript/blog/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because JS is executed first before any change. There are many things you can do.

1. Use a different way to show alert, like an overlay.
2. Use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
3. Trigger an [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) after the hide, and bind the alert to that event.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution, It will show the `alert` when the hide will complete. It will not depend on your system's performance.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#headerDiv').hide({done: function() { alert("something want to say!"); } });
  //** you can still add a delay */
  //$('#headerDiv').hide({done: function() { setTimeout(function(){alert("Hiding complete!") },100) }});
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="headerDiv"> headerDiv headerDiv</div>
```